# Setting enum member of class gives invalid use of ‘enum'

Tags: c++

```
class A{
    public:
        enum b{C,D};  
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.b = A::C;

    return 0;
}
```

I get

```
main.cpp:21:7: error: invalid use of ‘enum A::b’
     a.b = A::C;
       ^
```

Why? As I understand, my enum `b` is public and I could simply set it to any value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
enum b {C,D};
```

which defines `b` as a type, to

```
enum {C,D} b;
```

which declares `b` as an instance of an unnamed enum.

Answer (score 7):

`enum b{C,D};` creates a enum **type** named `b`.

If you want a **variable**, it needs to be created separately:

```
enum b{C,D};
b var;

// ...

a.var = A::C;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `enum` is indeed public and you can set an `instance` of that `enum` to `A::C` or `A::D`. However, this line

```
enum b{C, D};
```

defines the enumeration, but doesn't declare an instance of it. Hence,

```
a.b = A::C;
```

tries to assign an enumerator to the *type* `a.b`. You can fix this by

```
enum b{C,D} instance;
```

and then later

```
a.instance = A::C;
```

Answer (score 1):

An enum is a type, not a variable. You can create a variable with your enum as type, but that is not what you have done. Try this instead (I renamed some stuff, because that hopefully makes it more clear what is happening):

```
class A {
public:
    enum Color { Red, Green };
    Color color;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.color = A::Red;

    return 0;
}
```

Or as @lubgr pointed out:

```
class A {
public:
    enum Color { Red, Green } color;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.color = A::Red;

    return 0;
}
```